# Execute script when DropDownListFor item changed ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have a DropDownListFor like this :

```
    <div class="drop-down-list">
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StageId, ViewBag.StagesList as SelectList,new { @id="stageOne"})%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StageId) %>
    </div>
```

When the selected item changed I need to fire sth like code below to go to controller, fill a viewbag and populate another DropDownListFor. Actually I want to build two cascading DropDownListFor in asp.net mvc.

```
  <script>
    $('#stageOne').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Shop/ChangeStageTwo/',
            data: { item: $("#drop-down-list").sortable('toString') },
            type: 'post',
            traditional: true 
        });

    });
  </script>
```

But nothing happens when the user changes the first DropDownListFor . What is the problem?? Many thanks.

Comment: when you say nothing happens you mean the function is not triggered? put an alert in the function to see if it runs. Maybe url path is incorrect?

Comment: Yes , I mean that the function is not triggered. I tried the alert test. But the function is not triggered.

Comment: What happens if you wrap your jquery in  `$(function(){..add .change function here..});`? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Michael_B said, I changed code to this, and the problem solved :

```
 $(function () {
   $('#stageOne').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Shop/ChangeStageTwo/',
            data: { item: $("#drop-down-list").sortable('toString') },
            type: 'post',
            traditional: true 
        });

    });
 });
```